# how to delete a particular key from low-level cache API in django

Tags: python, django

In my django app,I am using the low level cache api

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

There is a situation that instead of clearing the whole cache,I need to delete a particular key.The problem here is that I do not know the key name - `but only that the keyname starts with a particular username string`

say `damon_my222cachekey` is a key that exists in cache.I only know that it starts witha a string `damon_`  .Is there some way I can tell cache to `delete a key` which starts with that particular string?

If there was some method like cache.keys() ,I could have used a regex expression to get the keyname from the returned list

Any help appreciated

Comment: no, don't think that's possible because keys are hashed

Comment: the keys are not hashed. though the key of the cached template fragments are generated basically by concatenating the name of the fragment and the hash of the concatenation of the tag parameters.

Comment: and how come that you don't know the key name? why do you put something in the cache if you are unable to regenerate its key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way to do this is to create two level cache. In this approach you don't in fact delete keys but makes them inaccessable (cache will delete them automatically in some time).

```
def get_user_version(username):
    version = cache.get("%s_version" % username)
    if version is None:
        version = random.randint(1, 1000000000)
        cache.set("%s_version" % username, version)
    return version

def get_user_cache(username, key):
    version = get_user_version(username)
    return cache.get("%s_%d_%s" % (username, version, key))

def set_user_cache(username, key, value):
    version = get_user_version(username)
    cache.set("%s_%d_%s" % (username, version, key), value)

def invalidate_user_cache(username):
    version = cache.incr("%s_version" % username)
```

The upside is that you can easly invalidate cache for user. Downside is that you make two requests to cache instead of one.